# Difference between the semilog function and plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I don't understand when to use the semilogx or semilogy function in Matlab and when to use the plot function,for example for displaying the spectrum of a signal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`semilogx` will scale the x-axis logarthmically, the same applies for `semilogy` on the y-axis. The data is exactly the same but sometimes it can be easier to view data where your axes are scaled like this. For example compare the two plots below.

```
x = [0.01 0.1 1 10 100 1e3 10e3];
subplot(121);
plot(x, '-o');
grid on;
subplot(122);
semilogy(x, '-o');
grid on;
```

You can access the documentation for any MATLAB function using  `help` or `doc` as follows `doc semilogx`